# Can't fade out with FadeInOutSampleProvider

Tags: naudio

I'm trying to use NAudio's `FadeInOutSampleProvider` to fade in a sample *and* fade it out. The fade in works OK, but instead of fading out gradually I get abrupt silence from where the fade-out should begin.

What's the correct way to fade out with `FadeInOutSampleProvider`?

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```cs
IWaveProvider waveSource; // initialised by reading a WAV file

// The ISampleProvider will be the underlying source for the following operations
ISampleProvider sampleSource = waveSource.ToSampleProvider();

// Create a provider which defines the samples we want to fade in
// (including the full-volume "middle" of the final output)
ISampleProvider fadeInSource = new OffsetSampleProvider(sampleSource);
fadeInSource.TakeSamples = most_of_file; // calculation omitted for brevity

// Create a provider which defines the samples we want to fade out:
// We will play these samples when fadeInSource is finished
ISampleProvider fadeOutSource = new OffsetSampleProvider(sampleSource);
fadeOutSource.SkipOverSamples = fadeInSource.TakeSamples;

// Wrap the truncated sources in FadeInOutSampleProviders
var fadeIn = new FadeInOutSampleProvider(fadeInSource);
fadeIn.BeginFadeIn(500); // half-second fade
var fadeOut = new FadeInOutSampleProvider(fadeOutSource);
fadeOut.BeginFadeOut(500);
// doc-comments suggest the fade-out will begin "after first Read"
```

I'm expecting `fadeOut` to initially read non-zero samples from 500ms before the end of the original source, but fade out to zeros by the end of the source.

However, when I play `fadeIn` to completion, then play `fadeOut`, I find that the *very first* `Read` call to `fadeOut` fills the buffer with zeros.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a bug in NAudio?

---

Note: I'm handling the sequential playback using a `ConcatenatingSampleProvider` which I implemented myself — I can't anything similar in NAudio's API. It's pretty trivial, so I've omitted the source here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to reuse `sampleSource` twice in your graph. So `sampleSource` has already been read to the end before anything is read from `fadeOutSource`. Probably for your usage, it would be better for `FadeInOutSampleProvider` to be able to "schedule" a fade-out after a known number of samples.

An alternative approach is a `FadeOutSampleProvider` that caches the fade-out duration, and then when it detects the end of its source has been reached, it returns the cached portion faded out. It does mean latency is introduced.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you suggest a `FadeOutSampleProvider`, do you mean I should implement that myself? Also, thanks very much for your work on NAudio.

Comment: yes, the idea with NAudio is for you to build your own sample providers, and chain them together. If you create one that works well and would be useful to others it could be added to the library.